# Add callback after render function is executed in forio/contour

Tags: javascript, charts, callback, forio-contour

It's possible to use callback function after method render is executed ?

E.g. I need change position of right tick - because one digit from it value is not visible. I want add this code.

```
var rightTick = $('#ptm-scatter-chart g.x.axis g.tick:last text');
rightTick.attr('x', rightTick.attr('x') - 10);
```

If I use this code just after calling

```
new Contour({

}).render();
```

it doesn't work.

If I put call of my function in `window.setTimeout` - code work, but this is ugly method.

Also I tried to use construction

```
Contour.export('myFunc', function(data, layer, options){

});
```

In this case myFunc can be called only before `render()` method, but I need execute it after render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that the x attribute will be overridden after the transitions complete. For your specific use case, you can set the 'dx' attribute to adjust the position, something like this:

```
var rightTick = $('#ptm-scatter-chart g.x.axis g.tick:last text');
rightTick.attr('dx', -10);
```

Here's a fiddle with the working code:

http://jsfiddle.net/z6vvutgo/

Hope this helps.

Jaime

Comment: It works, thank you.
It also works if put this code to `Contour.export('function')`